# Continue Mule flow on error

Tags: exception, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have a mule flow which consists of a scatter gather and a transform message.  If the scatter gather fails I would still like to continue to the transform message connector as it has exception handling for what error message should be mapped by Dataweave as well as using the lookup command to call a different flow flow determined on the error encountered.

Is it possible to continue the flow if the scatter gather fails?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you put the Transform in your exception strategy?

Comment: Yeah, I would just catch the exception in your exception strategy like @nitgeek suggested. That should allow you to continue the flow if the scatter gather fails.

Answer (score 0):

Create a flow with a catch exception strategy and add a flow ref to that flow. If an error is encountered in that flow the message will proceed to the component after the flow reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a filter expression on the payload and call the errorhandler and pass the exception caught in the scatter-gather. In the catch flow add your transformation activity and do whatever processing you wanna do.